# Why checking WizardForm for null in inno setup is not working?

Tags: inno-setup, pascal, pascalscript

Why is this not working?

```
if WizardForm <> nil then
  WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption := 'blah'
else
  Log('WizardForm not initialized yet!');
```

I get this exception:

```
Runtime Error (at 15:118):
Internal error: An attempt was made to access WizardForm before it has been created.
```

I know that WizardForm is not yet initialized, that's why I check for nil, the check is not working!
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens to every access of the `WizardForm` variable including the check, if it's assigned. Simply move your code from `InitializeSetup` event to `InitializeWizard`.

Comment: Is there any other way to check for null?

Comment: I use a procedure for some common job before and after initialization and I want to keep the same piece of code.

Comment: Sorry, but some things seems incomprehensible to me, being a software engineer mainly with Java for over 10 years! Who is to blame here for not being able to do a simple (to my eyes) check? Inno, Pascal Script, Pascal?

Comment: Yes, you can use `Assigned`, but in your case the same exception will be raised. You just can't access the `WizardForm` variable in any way. So to resolve what you need, I would simply set a new variable called e.g. `SetupInitialized: Boolean` and set it to True at the end of the `InitializeSetup` event method.

Comment: It is the Inno Setup's `WizardForm` getter, who has [`this hardcoded`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/master/Projects/ScriptFunc_R.pas#L90). Yes, it could have just return `nil` instead of that error.

Comment: I will go with your recommendation. I know I am not supposed to write 'thanks' here, but I just have to: THANKS!

Comment: @TLama: that's what it used to do, but people kept trying to access it from the wrong places and couldn't figure out the null variable access error (which to be fair, is because it's the generic "could not call proc" error, which isn't exactly obvious).  So a more meaningful error message was added in its place.

Comment: @Miral, I thought that was the reason.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any other way to check for null?

How about this:

```
function IsWizardFormCreated(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
  try
    WizardForm;
  except
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```